# Day Schools in Wizarding world?

Tags: harry-potter

Do they have ordinary day schools in the Wizarding World? Or is the Wizard population too thinly spread for this to be possible?

Comment: In the whole wizarding world? Or just the Britain, where there's canonically only one school for witches and wizards?

Comment: Day schools for magic specifically, or are you asking if there's an equivalent of Wizarding Kindergarten or elementary school where kids learn how to read and do math and that sort of thing before going off to learn witchcraft?

Comment: I was thinking primarily of magic ones/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most witches and wizards are homeschooled by parents, and only a select few families send their kids off to Hogwarts, or any of the other Wizarding Schools. I recommend you look at this Pottermore article, it's written by Rowling herself.

https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools

Comment: If the article is relevant you should edit in some relevant quotes in case the link goes down.